# Обращение к константе класса через строку

Tags: php

К примеру, у меня есть следующий класс:

```
class position
{
 const MANAGER = "Менеджер";
 const MARKETER = "Маркетолог";
}
```

Я хочу получить значение, но при этом у меня есть

```
position:: и строка "MANAGER"
```

Вот вопрос. Как я могу обратиться к классу, и получить значение этого атрибута?

Comment: А можно спросить - зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

второй вариант - функция [`constant()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)

```
echo constant( position::class . "::MANAGER");
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, таким образом, через специальный класс ReflectionClass:

```
$string = "MANAGER";
$obj = new ReflectionClass('position');
echo $obj->getConstant($string);
```